# Lightning inspector not working after taking action on components

Tags: lightning

I have lightning inspector installed and it is showing me the statistics when I navigate to VF page that contains my lightning component. But, if I click or do some onchange action, it is not giving me statistics. What could be possible reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to enable debug mode for lightning. After that lightning inspector details can be viewed. Missed the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_debug_mode.htm)